# How to filter multiple field conditionally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How to filter conditionally multiple field in Javascript.

Hi, i want to filter some data in javascript using filter, but in this case i want to accept to values, basicly what i'm trying todo is i want to create some search input then return the data, but i also want when the user type `category` in search input the result also show the category

```
const items = [
    { name: "Magazine", category: "Book"},
    { name: "Marker", category: "Pen"},
    { name: "Litelature", category: "Book"},
    { name: "Comics", category: "Book"},
    { name: "Drawer", category: "Pen"}
]
```

here i already implement the search filter.

```
const input = "Pen"
const filtered = items.filter((item) =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
)
```

as you can see that code return nothing since only filtering the name field. how can i implement filter also to the category field

Comment: Do you mean `filter(a => a.f1==x && a.f2==y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `or` condition, like

```
const input = "Pen"
const filtered = items.filter((item) =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()) ||
    item.category.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
)
```